# BB10 start applications from command line

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, blackberry-10

I've followed the instructions here:
[BB10 Cascades Command Line Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811027/bb10-cascades-command-line-development)

Now I've got a makefile project, which can compile and deploy my application to a connected device. The only problem is, I can't start the application remotely. I've created a special test version, which simply runs an automated test and then quits, so the next logical step would be starting the application, and waiting for it to exit (it would be great if I could monitor stdout and stderr) or kill it if it takes too long.

What I'm trying to accomplish (to avoid the xy problem) is the integration with a Jenkins server we already use for other platforms. E.g.: on Android we use robotium to achieve the same degree of integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

blackberry-nativepackager allows you to launch the application similar to androids adb.

Just call it like

```
blackberry-nativepackager -launchApp <path to bar file> -device <devices ip address> -password <your pwd>
```